# What are the steps to be able to connect to a mysql database on linux from windows

Tags: php, mysql, linux, windows

On my localhost (windows) I am trying to connect to 192.168.0.16 (linux box).

I have the appropriate connection function. (I have tested the function, it works. the question at hand is not the function, but the changes I must do to linux)

```
function dbOpen(){
    $host = '192.168.0.16:3306';
    $database = '';
    $username = '';
    $password = '';
    $dbCon = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
}
```

I get :
"cannot connect because the target machine actively refused it"

Are there things that I need to DO in LINUX in order to access the mysql database in linux from windows?

My goal here is to be able to have linux run the database/website while I can test on my localhost but still remotely connect to mysql (192.168.0.16) and manage it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mysql server settings problem. Try to edit the my.cnf file.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: You're welcome. Please tick that this answer was useful.